# How do I fix some Unity Build Compiler Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, export

[image: The Image]

Hi! I am making a 3d Game using the unity Game Engine and am trying to export the project (pc). This error occurs when I try to build the game for the windows platform. In the error, it says that the error has something to do with 'policy' in a teleporter script. It comes up with these following compiler errors. I have attached an image of the error screen below. Please tell me if I need to elaborate on the errors.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the TeleportEvent script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TeleportEvent script references Policy and doesn't know what class its referring to. You need to import the class, hover your mouse and alt + enter will give you suggestions in visual studio.

Comment: Oh thank you I think that is the problem now it works perfectly